# Send keypress as parameters in function

Tags: c#, keypress

I have a combobox, if the "Enter" key is pressed will do something. but i want to call this function manually but how i send "ENTER" key as parameter?

```
 private void carga_todos(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    { 
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {
           do something
        }
```

im trying this:

```
carga_todos(null, ??????)
```

Comment: NO NEED TO USE ALL CAPS FOR TITLES. KTHX.

Comment: I think OP was listening to metal while writing the title.

Comment: Can't this be blocked by the forum software?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't call events manually like that.

Move your logic into a separate method, which you can call whenever you like:

```
private void carga_todos(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
       DoSomething();
    }
}

private void AnotherFunctionThatNeedsToDoSomethingToo()
{
    DoSomething();
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    // stuff to do
}
```

Comment: thanks, omg how i didnt notice this!!, i was complicating all.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Grant Winney. However, if your requirements are to call the handler directly then the following should work:

```
KeyPressEventArgs kpea = new KeyPressEventArgs((char)Keys.Enter);
carga_todos(null, kpea);
```

Good luck
J